# Adding 3-Second Sound at Specific Time in Video Using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need some assistance with adding a 3-second sound to my 1.10-minute video using FFMPEG. I would like to add the sound at specific times, such as the 20th second of the video. It's important that the video's duration and quality remain unchanged throughout the process. Would you be able to help me by providing a command to accomplish this? I tried the following commands.

There are probably codec differences, frequency differences, etc. between the audio file and the video file.

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -i input_audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1[a1];[1:a]volume=1[a2];[a1]adelay=20000|20000[a3];[a3][a2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy output_video.mp4


ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -i input_audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=1[a1];[1:a]volume=1[a2];[a1]atrim=0:10[a4];[a1]atrim=10:100[a5];[a2]atrim=0:3[a6];[a4][a6][a5]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy output_video.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first command is almost there. Except you applied the delay to the main audio.

`ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -i input_audio.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=20000|20000[a1];[0:a][a1]amix=inputs=2:normalize=0:duration=first[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy output_video.mp4`

Make sure ffmpeg version is 4.4 or newer.

Comment: ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -i input_audio.aac -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=20000|20000[a1];[0:a][a1]amix=inputs=2:duration=first[aout]" -map 0:v -map "[aout]" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental output_video.mp4

Comment: am i correct in saying this can be only done with 1 audio file at a time? i'm trying to add multiple audio files at various times and getting `"[fc#0 @ 0x7fdd01005f40] Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [1:a]adelay=3620|3620[a1];[2:a]adelay=10120|10120[a2];[0:a][a1][a2]amix=inputs=3 matches no streams.\n" +
    'Error initializing complex filters: Invalid argument\n'`

Comment: One of your inputs does not have an audio stream.